How to store data in SQL server in different languages for language translation in a lengthy table?
I am working on a C# .NET application that needs to support the translated state names, districts, sub-districts, and villages into over 20 languages. Given that there are over 100,000 records for villages and sub-districts both, I am evaluating different strategies for storing and managing these translations.
I am told to figure out some solution where length of table will not be too long and not too many new tables need to created.
Here are the solutions I’m considering:

Storing Translations as JSON or XML

VillageID   Name    Translations
    1   Village A   {"en": "Village A", "fr": "Village A - FR", "de": "Dorf A", "es": "Villa A", "hi": "गांव ए"}


Transaction table

VillageTranslations Table

    VillageID   Name
    1           Village A
    2           Village B
    3           Village C
    
 TranslationID  VillageID   LanguageCode    TranslatedName
    1           1           en              Village A
    2           1           fr              Village A - FR
    3           1           de              Dorf A
    4           1           es              Villa A
    5           2           en              Village B
    6           2           fr              Village B - FR
    7           3           en              Village C
    8           3           hi              गांव सी

Creating a new transaction table will require re-writing all the APIs and queries will take too long

NoSQL like Database Option

{
    "_id": 1,
        "state_name": {
            "en": "California",
            "es": "California",
            "fr": "Californie"
        }
    }

I have never used this kind of solution. So I am unaware of drawbacks.
I am searching for the best approach.

What is the solution you have today?

By using a Translation table with a JSON field, you can store translations for different tables and columns in a flexible way. Here's the schema
Translation
type:         string         // table name
targetId:     int            // id of the record to be translated 
code:         string         // the language code            
texts:        json           // JSON field to store translated properties of the record

For example, if you have an record like:
Event = { id: 1, name: 'Name', description: 'Description' }

You can add translations for any language using a Translation entry like this:
Translation = { 
    type: 'Event', 
    targetId: 1, 
    code: 'en', 
    texts: { 
        name: 'Name (translated)', 
        description: 'Description (translated) 
    }
}

This approach is particularly beneficial when you have multiple tables and columns that require translation. It centralizes the translation logic and makes it easier to manage multilingual data across your entire application
